# Ampscript conditional statement in style tag?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, css

Can I have an AmpScript conditional statement in a  tag?

```
%%[SET @email = [emailaddress]
   SET @domain = Domain(@email)
]%%
%%[IF @domain != "gmail.com" OR @domain != "yahoo.com" OR @domain != "mac.com" OR @domain != "icloud.com" THEN]%%    
select {
display: none !important; 
    mso-hide: all; 
    visibility:hidden;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-size:0;
    width:0;
    height:0;
    max-height:0; 
    overflow:hidden;
    border: 0 !important;
    outline: 0px solid #ffffff !important; 
    outline-offset:-1px !important;
}
%%[ENDIF]%%
```

Comment: AmpScript code can be use any where in HTML, CSS, JavaScript and JQuery.